# Object Rotation in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game

I have two in-the-game objects which are the stone and  arrow that attach to the vehicle

arrow has attributes of x, y, z,
rotation, rotation y, rotation z

Changing rotation x will make the arrow turn left and right, the rotation y is the up and down and z is like the wing

What I want is to point the arrow into the position of the stone

I appreciate any help

To make arrow that attach to vehicle point to the stone

Comment: Added - it's like waypoint system

Answer (score 0):

I think transform LookAt is what you're after.

```cs
arrow.tranform.LookAt(stone.transform);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html